# Dynamic url re-writing using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite http://mydomain.com/test/master.php?catid=2&subcatid=8 to http://mydomain.com/test/master.php/catname/subcat using a .htaccess file.

Once rewritten, how can I access these parameters in master.php?

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is untested, let me know if it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^master.php/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /master.php?catid$1&subcatid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: When you rewrite a url like this, you can still use :

    $_GET['catid'];

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But i access my page like http://mydomain.com/test/master.php/catname/subcat, still we get error like "The requested URL /master.php was not found on this server". Please correct me if i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hang on, where are you putting the .htaccess - is there a folder called "test", if so, put it in there. If not, put it in the root and alter the above code to :

    RewriteRule ^test/master.php/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /test/master.php?catid$1&subcatid=$2 [L]

Comment: basically, its trying to find /master.php - but this file does not exist. /test/master.php does.